# Properly extending ExtJS component without overwriting listeners

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

Consider the following example class `Parent`:

```
Ext.define('Parent', {

    ...
    listeners: {
        render: {
            fn: doSomething
        },
    },
```

};

and the following class `Child` extending default `Parent` above:

```
Ext.define('Child', {
    extend: 'Parent',

    ...
    listeners: {
        afterrender: {
            fn: doSomething
        },
    },
};
```

Even though `Child` does not specify a listener for `render` (it only provides for `afterrender`) the `render` listener (defined in the `Parent` class) is not fired anymore upon `Child`'s component rendering; i.e. the listener is *overwritten* by the new *listeners* specification.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can specify the handler in `initComponent`, instead of using the `listeners` config object.

```
Ext.define('Child', {
    extend: 'Parent',

    ...
    initComponent: function() {
        this.on('afterrender', this.onAfterRender);
    },

    onAfterRender: function() {
        ...
    }
};
```

The reason that the `listeners` config method doesn't work is [because the config object that is passed to `Ext.define` gets `Ext.apply`'d](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?143869-How-to-properly-extend-components-in-ExtJS-4.&p=637517&viewfull=1#post637517) to any new objects that are created. In other words, it completely overwrites any reference types (e.g. the `listeners` object).

Using `initComponent` is preferred, since it's specifically designed to be overridden for subclassing.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is no clean solution in the framework at the moment; however something a bit kludgy like this can be used relatively safe:

```
Ext.define('Child', {
    extend: 'Parent',

    listeners: Ext.merge(Parent.prototype.listeners || {}, {
        ...
    })
});
```

I must admit that it's not much better than using `initComponent` but at least it's a bit more declarative.

Comment: Works, and as you say more declarative, +1ed.

Comment: Note that this will alter the Parent.prototype.listeners! http://stackoverflow.com/a/15481693/385995

Answer (score 2):

"Fixed" issue by declaring the event handler within `initComponent` using `on`. So the sample code for the child class would be:

```
Ext.define('Child', {
    extend: 'Parent',

    ...
    initComponent : function(args) {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(args);
        me.on('afterrender', me.doSomething, this);
    },
};
```

Still doesn't look that nice to me; if anyone has a better solution, please answer the question.

Comment: Actually, I believe that is the preferred method. `initComponent` is specifically made for this purpose. There's only so much you can do with config objects...

Answer (score 0):

In version 6.02 configuring viewConfig with a new method in a child, will still keep other methods within viewConfig from the parent. Really good.