# Extjs merge objects

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a super class in my application, that defines an object like this:

```
Ext.define('superclass', {
    myObject: {
        prop1: true,
        prop2: 200,
        ..
    }
```

and a child class that inherited the superclass above, that declares the same object:

```
Ext.define('childclass', {
    extend: 'superclass',

    myObject: {
        prop3: false,
        prop4: false,
        ..
    }
```

The problem is with that, the myObject in the child class has only the prop3 and prop4 properties.

I need that myObject ib child class has all prop1, prop2, prop3 and prop4 properties.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extend the object in the constructor (or in initComponent if you extend Ext.Component):

```
Ext.define('childclass', {
    extend: 'superclass',

    constructor: function() {
        this.myObject = Ext.apply({}, this.myObject, {
            prop3: false,
            prop4: false
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/9xsyS/).

Comment: This (and the Ext.merge solution) will change `myObject` on the superclass prototype, which doesn't seem like desirable behavior.

Comment: You may want to flip the arguments and make this.myObject the third (default) argument to Ext.apply. The way it is now the childclass' custom properties won't be able to override the superclass properties since myObject's properties will be applied overtop of the child ones.

Comment: Yeah true, didn't think that one through

Comment: Why this is the accepted and higher rated answer than wantok's below is anyone's guess. Make sure you read the comments. Overriding prop1/2 would fail with this (it's not part of the question, so the answer is not wrong, but this will apply to many using this solution).

Answer (score 3):

Both of the provided answers will change the superclass prototype's myObject property as soon as a child class is constructed. This may not be what you want. I question why you are putting an object on the class prototype like this. It's generally not a good idea to do it. But if you really want to, you can do this

```
Ext.define('childclass', {
    extend: 'superclass',

    // I'm adding an empty object here so that myObject on the
    // prototype does not get overridden.
    myObject: Ext.merge({}, superclass.prototype.myObject, {
        prop3: false,
        prop4: false
    });

});
```

Comment: This works, but now, I need to include a "require" to the superclass in the child class. This is correct ?

Comment: In my case, I'm using the Deftjs libs, where I need to declare a "control" object in the class, the bind elements.

Comment: @paulo You would need to require the superclass before defining the childclass I think. In the project I'm working on we don't use Ext.Loader and the superlcass would already be included so it's something I didn't consider.

Comment: Much better than the currently accepted answer, and was also correct earlier.

Answer (score 0):

@Molecular man's answer is correct, however I would use the merge function.

Lets say you have this in your first config:

```
myObject: {
   prop1: false,
   person: {
       name: "John"
   }
}
```

And your second object

```
myObject: {
   prop2: false,
   person: {
       surname: "Doe"
   }
}
```

Your apply will overwrite person and you'll only have `person.surname`.

Into something like this:

```
myObject: {
   prop1: false,
   prop2: false,
   person: {
       surname: "Doe"
   }
}
```

Merge will merge the two objects.

```
Ext.define('childclass', {
    extend: 'superclass',

    constructor: function() {
        this.myObject = Ext.merge(this.myObject, {
            prop3: false,
            prop4: false
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Note that this will only be needed in the sitation as described in my example, if not you can use Molecular's answer.

Comment: I´m facing a problem with this solution and Molecular Man also. It looks like the myObject keeps this new properties even for new instantiate objects (lest´s, another child class type deriving this superclass).